# Migrating multi-type indices to single-type indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We started to use Elasticsearch 5.6 couple of years ago for our product search. Now we want to switch to a more recent version. As we all know from version 6.0 Elasticsearch doesn't support multi-type indices, we need to convert from multi-type indices to single-type indices. We used to search/ dump data in a particular type with url like "/index/type1". If we convert this "type1" doc-type into new indices, then should we also change our urls from "index/type1" to "type1/"? Is there any way we can switch to recent Elasticsearch version without changing those urls?

Comment: Which ES version do you intend to migrate to?

Comment: @val we intend to migrate in elasticsearch 7.4

Comment: Yes, the URLs will need to change as well. `index/type1` will become `type1/_doc` (in ES 7) and simply `type1` in ES8

Comment: Thank you :)  though changing those url would be painful

Comment: That's unfortunately how it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the URLs will need to change as well.

In ES 5 you have `index/type1`...

In ES 7 that will become `type1/_doc`...

And in ES 8 it will simply be `type1`

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) for more info